# Convert bytes string to decimal

Tags: byte, decimal, ocaml

I'm looking for the easiest solution to convert from a bytes string (something of the form "\000\001\002\003") to a decimal number in OCaml.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, bytes and string are two different types in OCaml. I'll assume you're talking about a string and not a value of type bytes.

If you're sure your input has the proper form you can just add '0' to every element, then use `int_of_string`.

```
let convert s =
    let s' =
        String.map
        (fun c -> Char.chr (Char.code c + Char.code '0'))
        s
    in
    int_of_string s'
```

Here's how it works:

```
# let convert = ...
val convert : string -> int = <fun>
# convert "\000\001\002\003";;
- : int = 123
```

For serious use you would want to verify that the input bytes are in the correct range. You could return a value of type `int option` (where `None` indicates that the input was invalid). Or you could raise an exception for invalid input.

Comment: What if the input has something of the from "\r" or "\t" or "\b"? Then your solution would not work because it would fail on the int_of_string call

Comment: Right, that's why I said the input should have a form like your example. Otherwise you need to specify the allowed forms for the input, nobody can guess them from your one example.